# Easiest way of producing a circle animation

Tags: animation, 3d, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate the Moon around the earth in Unity.

My questions are:

1. What is the easiest way to rotate the earth around its Center.
2. How can I rotate the Moon around the Earth?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [transform.RotateAround()](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) in the update function of the moon.

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class Orbit : MonoBehaviour
{
    /* the object to orbit */
    public Transform target;

    /* speed of orbit (in degrees/second) */
    public float speed;

    public Update()
    {
        if (target != null) {
            transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To make a moon rotate around the Earth, and the Earth rotate around the sun, you should make the moon a child of the Earth. Add the above script to it. Then it will be within the Earth's co-ordinate space, which means it will stay in the same relative position.
You can then attach the script to the Earth and child the Earth to the sun.

If you choose to take this approach I'd recommend changing the script like this:

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class Orbit : MonoBehaviour
{
    /* speed of orbit (in degrees/second) */
    public float speed;    

    public Update()
    {
        Transform target = transform.parent;

        if (target != null) {
            transform.RotateAround(target.position, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Fecal.
what about if i want to add another animation which will be like this :
the earth rotates around itself and in the same time it rotates around the sun.

I can't do more than one animation for one object in Unity3D?!!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this question until now. I changed the answer accordingly, but I imagine you probably worked this out already. Please tick my answer if it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming your model earth is already centered about its local coordinate system, you can modify `myEarth.Transform.localRotation` over time to animate its spin.
2. For rotating the moon around the earth, you'll first want to nest the moon as a child of the earth; this way, when the earth moves, the moon will still be positioned correctly relative to the earth. With the moon a child of the earth, you then have to animate the moon on an eliptical (or circular as an approx.) path around the origin (<0,0,0>) in earth-local-coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

What could help for your case to handle multiple animations in Unity3D, is to consider making it more easier for you by having overview on your animations' path. To narrow the border between thinking and actually doing an the animation work, I use [iTween](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/index.php) plugin to visuallise those paths of the animated object and to apply some more complex logics. For your case spacificly is to add rotation to the object and animate a path which it follows. There is quite a lot documented for using iTween and making such an animation could be easily done with it.